# Xpages: how can we implement localization for client side JS code?

Tags: javascript, dojo, internationalization, xpages

I'm currently developing a multi-lingual Xpages driven application using standard ways to localize static and dynamic strings through internal `.property` resources and `resourceBundles`. Within the application, users can choose their preferred language, this decision currently is stored in a user config document; I'm also planning to store those decisions as browser cookies. If there is no user defined preference the browser's default language drives the locale used within the application. This works fine for all server side elements.

Now I have to add some client side scripting, and I there need to use some localized strings as well. I have to admit that I don't have a clue which is the best approach for this.

Main questions are:

1. can I somehow use existing file resources / resource bundles?
2. if so: how can I reference those resources from my script code?
3. if not: what's the best way to organize and reference my own file resources?
4. finally: if I have to do it all by myself: how do I find out which locale is the user's preferred one? That one is easy if a cookie is set (see above), but what if I need to reference the browser's preference and/or if a user has disallowed usage of cookies?

*Edit:* I considered going the [dojo i18n way](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/i18n.html#dojo-i18n), but I don't know how to implement such a custom plugin.

Comment: I think the best way is the Java way. In CSJS you can insert also ssjs to get the labels from the backed bean, may be my blogs can help. http://elstarit.nl/2016/03/08/xpages-tip-add-a-new-language-to-your-app/

Comment: thanks for the comment, @FrankvanderLinden. Appears to be a very helpful approach for maintaining those resources, I'll read through it more thoriughly over the next few days

Comment: I you need help, let me know, you have my blog ;-)

Comment: I use the following approach: In my CSJS libraries I use an EL-like notation to mark translateable parts, for example `var text="#{TRLT.TextToTranslate}";`. Instead of directly referencing the libraries in the html head, I reference a helper xpage (js.xsp) that behaves like a JavaScript resource (Content-Type=text/javascript). This XPage loads all the CSJS libraries, concatenates them and replaces the translateable parts with strings from the dictionary I also use for the server-side translations. I could post some code, but I guess there are much simpler solutions to your problem...

Comment: This sounds very interesting. I'd love to see some kind of example, if you don't mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative is to read the resource bundles directly in the browser and reference that in JavaScript where you need it. So to answer your main questions:

1. Yes, but if you load it directly from the NSF it's not really usable yet. I would recommend to create an XPage to output it for you as a JSON object:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" rendered="false">

   <xp:this.resources>
       <xp:bundle
       src="/labels_en.properties"
       var="translations">
       </xp:bundle>
   </xp:this.resources>

   <xp:this.afterRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:
   try {

    var externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    var writer = facesContext.getResponseWriter();
    var response = externalContext.getResponse();

    response.setContentType("application/json"); 

    var jsonOutput = {};
    var keys = translations.keySet();

    for (var key in keys) {
      jsonOutput[key] = translations[key];
    }

    writer.write(  "var translations = " + toJson(jsonOutput)  ) ;
    writer.endDocument();

   } catch (e) {
       print(e);
   }
   }]]>
       </xp:this.afterRenderResponse>

   </xp:view>
   ```
2. You need to include the XPage from 1. as a client side JavaScript library on your page. I created a global JavaScript variable called `translations` in the XPage from 1. so you can call it as `translations.key` where `key` references a variable from the properties file.
3. No answer needed...
4. In the XPage from answer 1, you can load the appropriate resource bundle based on the user's locale (browser language setting):

   ```
   <xp:this.resources>
       <xp:bundle var="translations">
       <xp:this.src><![CDATA[#{javascript:
   var language = "en";        //default language

   switch (context.getLocaleString() ) {
   case "nl":
       language = "nl";
       break;
   }

   return "/labels_" + language + ".properties";}]]></xp:this.src>
       </xp:bundle>
   </xp:this.resources>
   ```

Comment: great stuff! One more Q regarding the internal property format: do you use a JSON format as in {"key": "value"} or is it the XSP standard format as in "key=value" as is created and maintained by the engine itself?

Comment: never mind, just found out myself: you're converting the standard "key=value" format into a json object, right?

Comment: Correct. You can use the standard `key=value` format.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following approach: All my client-side JavaScript (CSJS) libraries are stored as file resources in the database design (Resources > Files). In the code of the libraries I use an **EL-like notation** to mark translateable parts, for example:

```
var text="#{TRLT.TextToTranslate}";
```

Whenever I want to use the libraries on a XPage, I do not directly reference them in the XPage's resources, but add a reference to a "Helper-XPage" (js.xsp) instead:

```
<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:headTag tagName="script">
        <xp:this.attributes>
            <xp:parameter name="src" value="js.xsp?lng=#{sessionScope.language}&amp;v=#{applicationScope.versionApp}"/>
            <xp:parameter name="type" value="text/javascript"/>
        </xp:this.attributes>
    </xp:headTag>
</xp:this.resources>
```

The js.xsp behaves like a JavaScript resource: I set `rendered="false"` on the XPage and manually create a response with `Content-Type="text/javascript"` in the **beforeRenderResponse** event. When the XPage is called, **it reads all CSJS libraries, concatenates them and fills in all the translations** based on the dictionaries that I generally use for server-side translations.

Here is the code for the beforeRenderResponse event of js.xsp:

```
importPackage(java.io);
importPackage(java.lang);
importPackage(java.util.regex);
importPackage(javax.servlet.http);
importPackage(org.apache.commons.io); // AFAIK this package is not installed by default (but generally very helpful)

var i,arr,lng,js,libs,c,s,m,bfr,dct,response,ec,is,os;

//---------------------------- initialize main variables
ec=facesContext.getExternalContext(); // the external context

lng=(param.lng || "en");  // the language can be provided as url parameter, otherwise use a default

dct=(applicationScope["TRLT_"+lng] || {}); // in my case, the dictionaries (HashMaps) containing the translations are stored in the applicationScope, but of course they can be loaded from anywhere (resource bundles etc.)

libs=(param.libs ? fromJson(param.libs) : ["mylib1.js","mylib2.js"]) // the library names can be provided as url parameter, otherwise use a default

//---------------------------- concatenate all libraries
js=new StringBuilder();
for (i=0;i<libs.length;i++) {
    if (s=IOUtils.toString(ec.getResourceAsStream(libs[i]),"UTF-8")) js.append("\n\n"+s);
}
js=js.toString();

//---------------------------- search for and replace translateable parts
m=Pattern.compile("[#$]\\{TRLT\\.([^}]+)\\}").matcher(js);
bfr=new StringBuffer();
c=0;
while (m.find() && c<1e6) {
    c++;
    s=m.group(1);
    m.appendReplacement(bfr,dct[s] || s || "");
}
m.appendTail(bfr);
js=bfr.toString();

//---------------------------- create the response and finalize
response=ec.getResponse();
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","max-age="+(60*60*24*365).toFixed(0)); // its important to set the expiration "a bit" into the future to prevent the browser from reloading the js.xsp everytime you reference it on another XPage; in order to force the browser to update the XPage, use versioning (see url parameter "v" in the headTag definition above)
response.setDateHeader("Expires",new Date().getTime()+(1000*60*60*24*365));
response.setHeader("Content-Type","text/javascript; name=\"libs.js\"");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=\"libs.js\"");

is=new ByteArrayInputStream(js.getBytes("UTF-8"));
os=response.getOutputStream();
IOUtils.copy(is,os);
is.close();
os.close();
facesContext.responseComplete();
return;
```

PS: I had to modify the codes presented here because the original versions have some dependecies to my general framework as well as some additional caching and error handling. Hence I can't guarantee that there are no typos, but in principle it should work.

Comment: many thanks; hard to decide which one of two similar answers I should accept; I chose the one from @MarkLeusink above as it is slightly simpler

Comment: @LotharMueller: The solution of Mark Leusink is much simpler to implement and more suitable for what you want to achieve. The reason I don't use this kind of approach is that my translation dictionaries are rather large (>5Mb) because they also contain HTML templates. Loading that much content on a HTML page results in a long loading time the first time a user accesses the page. If you furthermore forget setting the cache control headers this even happens every time the user loads the page. Of course I could create an extra dictionary for CSJS translations, but that makes it harder to maintain